# DataFrame .apply Function with Multiple Conditions returning ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where the **['used']** column sometimes has a value of 0 even when the **['required']** column has a value in the numbers list. When that is the case, it was an entry error, and I am trying to change the value in the **['used']** column to be equal to the **['required']** column value.

This is the function I tried to define. I prefer calling functions because lambda syntax with conditional statements can be confusing:

```
def missing_value(df):
    numbers = [20, 35, 75]
    for number in numbers:
        if (df['required']==number) and (df['used']==0):
            df['used']==df['required']

# Apply function on column
df = df.apply(missing_value(df), axis=1)
```

It keeps returning **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().** when I try to run the code.

Is the issue that the datatypes are not matched for the conditions or is my syntax for going row by row incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `df['required']==number` is not likely to work due to different lengths between `df` and `number`.
2. `and` expects a single boolean. Pandas does not know how to transform a series, e.g. `df['used'] == 0` into a single boolean.
3. you can just pass the function name without argument to `apply`. That is `df.apply(missing_value, axis=1)`, which by the way gives you a single column of `None` since you don't return anything inside your function.

That being said, you should not iterate in this case:

```
numbers = [20, 35, 75]
df.loc[df['used'].eq(0) & df['required'].isin(numbers), 'used'] = df['required']
```

Comment: I didn't  even realize you could  just use .loc to change values, that's such a simpler solution. Thank you very much!